# Add a tag to a Build when creating a release using deployment projects

Tags: release, bamboo

We are using Bamboo Global Build Expiry to clean up old builds and releases, but we use a special tag `release-build` to keep builds that are used as releases in deployment projects. Otherwise the build and artifacts will be deleted and we are left with a release where no artifacts exists.

My question now is, if I can add a tag to a build, when I create a new release in a deployment project. The fear is to forget to add the tag afterwards, so that Bamboo clean it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be possible using the basic Bamboo functionality in the UI as of Bamboo 5.12. See this answer for more details: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/24648788/how-to-automatically-add-label-for-deployed-prod-build

However, as mentioned there, you could create your own plugin to do this if you really wanted needed to. Alternatively, you might try to add it via a REST call triggered in a deployment project or at the completion of a successful release candidate: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/11991582/how-to-add-label-to-build-or-plan-using-bamboo-rest-api

Here's another resource that might be closer to what you're looking for using the REST API: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/labelling-a-build-from-a-deployment-plan-800715643.html

Comment: This looks promising